# Find randomly placed element (x,y) inside a grid

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Given a grid of size 1000, find the x and y coords of a randomly placed element.

I've tried subdividing the grid into four sections, but I also have to make the solution time-complexity efficient.

```
const GRID_SIZE = 1000

class RandomElement {
  constructor() {
    const element = {
      x: Math.floor(Math.random() * GRID_SIZE),
      y: Math.floor(Math.random() * GRID_SIZE)
    }
    this._element = element
  }

  findInArea(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    console.log(`Scanning area (${x1}, ${y1}, ${x2}, ${y2})`)
    return (
      this._element.x >= x1 &&
      this._element.y >= y1 &&
      this._element.x < x2 &&
      this._element.y < y2
    )
  }

  findInCell(x, y) {
    console.log(`Scanning cell (${x}, ${y}`)
    return this._element.x === x && this._element.y === y
  }
}

const RandomElement = new RandomElement()

const iselementHere1 = RandomElement.findInArea(0, GRID_SIZE, 0, GRID_SIZE)
console.log('Is element Here?', iselementHere1)

const iselementHere2 = RandomElement.findInArea(0, GRID_SIZE / 2, GRID_SIZE / 2, GRID_SIZE)
console.log('Is element Here?', iselementHere2)

const iselementHere3 = RandomElement.findInArea(GRID_SIZE / 2, 0, GRID_SIZE, GRID_SIZE / 2)
console.log('Is element Here?', iselementHere3)

const iselementHere4 = RandomElement.findInArea(GRID_SIZE / 2, GRID_SIZE / 2, GRID_SIZE, GRID_SIZE)
console.log('Is element Here?', iselementHere4)
```

Comment: Just off the top of my head... perhaps a 2-D version of binary search? Split the grid horizontally, ask if the item is in the top or the bottom half. Split the half that it's found in vertically, split that half horizontally, etc.

Comment: The question is, what is the most efficient way to find the randomly placed element. Right now, I'm creating four instances of the findInArea method to scan four different areas of the grid, and I'm still stopping short of nailing down the actual x and y coords of the randomly placed element

Comment: @shash678, the `findInArea` method he has defined shows that you don't have to know at each step exactly where the item being search for is specifically located, it's allowed that you get an answer if the item is in a broad area or not (the function that tells you that already knows exactly where the item is located). This should be n*log n.

Comment: Does your grid have some order? If yes you can use a binary search. If not, then your only solution is to check every cell until you get a result.

Comment: @Ripi2 there is no order in the grid, there is an x and a y axis though

Comment: Again, if the cells are x-sorted or y-sorted you can do a binary search. But if it's a "cloud" of points, that's randomness, no order.

Comment: @Ripi2 how would I go about doing that binary search?

Comment: There is a huge amount of entries in this site and on Internet about "binary search". Basically, start at the middle and select the half that satisfies your condition; then continue in the half of that half, etc.

Comment: I guess my question is, can someone provide an answer? Algorithms is not something I work on a daily basis, this was a coding challenge I failed for a front end engineer role and, I want to get it out of my system so to speak

Comment: @kshetline: Wouldn't this just be O(log(x) + log(y)). Basically, do a binary search rectangles that start with size (x/2,y), then (x/4,y), etc. until you get to (1,y). Now you know the column that it's in. That will take O(log x). Then binary search columns to find the row that it's in. Again, O(y).

Answer (score 0):

Expressions

```
xx = Math.floor(this._element.x / (GRID_SIZE / 2))
yy = Math.floor(this._element.y / (GRID_SIZE / 2))
```

give you cell coordinates in 2x2 grid.

You can combine both in single parameter

```
cellYX = xx + 2 * yy
```

to get result `0..3` as cell number

```
0  |  1
-------
2  |  3
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your 2d array into another 2d array where every index holds {value, x, y}. Now sort it row / column wise. Then every element search will take rlogc (sorted column-wise) / clogr (sorted row-wise) and just output the (x,y) of that index (it's not the actual co-ordinates, but the co-ordinates of the given 2d-array)